# No aparecen los alerts de JS en pantalla

Tags: javascript

Tengo que crear un objeto a partir de un constructor en JS que contenga una serie de propiedades y métodos, para luego crear un objeto nuevo e invocar sus métodos. El código es el siguiente:

```
<script>
    function Smartphone(marca, modelo, color, tamaño) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.color = color;
        this.tamano = tamano;

        this.instalarAplicacion = function(apli) {
            alert('Aplicación ' + ' instalada con éxito en smartphone ' + marca + ' ' + modelo);
        };

        this.enviarCorreo = function(mensa) {
            alert('Mensaje: ' + mensa + ' enviado con éxito');
        };

        this.llamar = function(num) {
            alert('Llamando al ' + num + ' desde mi smartphone con tamaño ' + tamano + ' pulgadas');
        };
    }

    var unSmartphone = new Smartphone('Samsung', 'S9', 'azul', '9');
    unSmartphone.instalarAplicacion('Chrome');
    unSmartphone.enviarCorreo('Hola mundo');
    unSmartphone.llamar(678897000);
</script>
```

Pues bien, no soy capaz de que salgan las ventanas de alerta por pantalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error en el nombre de la variable **tamaño**. Por parámetros esta con *ñ*, pero dentro de tu función la referencias con *n*.

```js
function Smartphone(marca, modelo, color, tamano) {
  this.marca = marca;
  this.modelo = modelo;
  this.color = color;
  this.tamano = tamano;

  this.instalarAplicacion = function(apli) {
      alert(`Aplicación instalada con éxito en smartphone ${marca} ${modelo}`);
  };

  this.enviarCorreo = function(mensa) {
      alert(`Mensaje: ${mensa} enviado con éxito`);
  };

  this.llamar = function(num) {
      alert(`Llamando al ${num} desde mi smartphone con tamaño ${tamano} pulgadas`);
  };
}

var unSmartphone = new Smartphone('Samsung', 'S9', 'azul', '9');
unSmartphone.instalarAplicacion('Chrome');
unSmartphone.enviarCorreo('Hola mundo');
unSmartphone.llamar(678897000);
```

> Como recomendación, trata de no utilizar carácteres especiales en el
> nombre de funciones y/o variables, ya que generalmente se utiliza
> sintaxis basado en idioma inglés, para evitar anomalías.

Nos comentas cualquier cosa ;)

Comment: Buenas Paulo,

Pues efectivamente eso era lo que tenía atascado todo el código :S

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, de verdad.

Saludos!

Comment: @dancareli realice una edición en la respuesta. Fijate que el `string` del `alert` ya no utiliza concatenación, sino que estoy utilizando `template strings`, el cual te ayuda a trabajar con variables dentro de un texto de una forma mucho más legible y fácil de implementar. Considera utilizar las comillas inclinadas cuando quieras juntar texto y variables :D. Saludos y bienvenido!

Comment: la verdad es que desconocía los template strings, y el tema de las comillas es más que nada porque estoy trabajando con Atom, y el plugin Beautify me identifica como error las comillas dobles, que las suelo utilizar siempre para no liarme entre lenguajes de programación. Muchas gracias por las recomendaciones y por la bienvenida :D